# Django processing multiple Forms from ListView

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using ListView class to display some items to the dashboard of the user currently logged in. I want to also include multiple forms on the dashboard that would allow the user to interact with these items (add new ones, edit existing etc)

However I would like to update my view without the user having to refresh the page (through AJAX). I've searched around for an answer but I haven't been able to find something that matches my needs.

```
class HomeDesktopViewAuth(FormMixin, ListView):
context_object_name = 'user'
form_class = BudgetSetForm
template_name='transactions/home_desktop_auth.html'

#if an unauthorised person tries to acces their profile redirect them to login page
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'))
def dispatch(self, *args,  **kwargs):
    return super(HomeDesktopViewAuth, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = User.objects.filter(username=self.request.user)
    return qs

#Add form to the context
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomeDesktopViewAuth, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = self.get_form()
    print(context)
    return context

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # From ProcessFormMixin
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    self.form = self.get_form(form_class)

    # From BaseListView
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
    allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()
    if not allow_empty and len(self.object_list) == 0:
        raise Http404(_(u"Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.")
            % {'class_name': self.__class__.__name__})

    context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list, form=self.form)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

This is my view for the dashboard so far and I'm not quite sure where to go from here so my form gets validated and an updated context is returned. I'm very new to Django so I'm not sure if what I have so far is implemented properly.

**What should I add to my view so it returns updated context data to my JS?**